# Create a map from a list of of a key in a element

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to convert a list of items into a map.
The element contains a key named tags that contains multiple tags separated by ','

The key should match all nodes that contains the tag.

```
variable "list" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [
    { a : "a", tags : "k1" },
    { a : "b", tags : "k1" },
    { a : "c", tags : "k1,k2" },
    { a : "d", tags : "k2" },
    { a : "e", tags : "k2" }
  ]
}
    
// Output wanted
// {
//  "k1" : [{a: a}, {a: b}, {a: c}],
//  "k2" : [{a: d}, {a: e}, {a: c}]
// }
```

I've tried:

```
[for n in var.list: {for t in split(",", n["tags"]): t => n}]

[
  {
    "k1" = {a: a}
  },
  {
    "k1" = {a: b}
  },
  {
    "k1" = {a: c},
    "k2" = {a: c}
  },
  {
    "k2" = {a: d}
  },
  {
    "k2" = {a: e}
  },
]
```

But I don't know how to merge it after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit trickier. I used two helper data types, `helper_list` and `helper_map`. The first one check what keys are there, `k1`, `k2`. The second
creates a list with individual values. The `final_map` converts `helper_map` into desired map:

```
locals {

  helper_list = distinct(flatten(
        [for n in var.list: [for t in split(",", n["tags"]): t]]))
        
  helper_map = flatten([
             for k in local.helper_list:
             [
               for item in var.list: 
               {"${k}" = {a = item["a"]}} if length(regexall(k, item["tags"])) > 0
             ]
           ])
        
  final_map = {for item in local.helper_map: keys(item)[0] => values(item)[0]...}
}


output "test1" {
   value = local.final_map
}
```

Outcome:

```
est1 = {
  "k1" = [
    {
      "a" = "a"
    },
    {
      "a" = "b"
    },
    {
      "a" = "c"
    },
  ]
  "k2" = [
    {
      "a" = "c"
    },
    {
      "a" = "d"
    },
    {
      "a" = "e"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: How could I change it to have a map instead of a list ? (key will be a field of the object)

Comment: @XciD Hi. I am not sure what you mean. You have list in the output wanted in the question.